# SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS

Tags: objective-c

will some body explain me in detail that what is SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS and why we should use it. actually i have search on net that it allow us to access a data without creating object but we can do that by using static method.
so plz if someone can provide me a ref where i can get complete detatil of SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS from zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html?

`SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS` is just a C macro defined that produce the same code template described in [Apple's *Creating a Singleton Instance* section of the *Cocoa Fundamentals Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32). This link already provides the detail what each method does.